# In Backbone.js, how do I create a custom .render() function for a few attributes, and direct all the others to the more global render function

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to say "when `question_number` changes, run `updateQuestionNumber`. If anything EXCEPT `question_number` (and whatever else I give a custom render function), run .render()".

The problem with the following code is that both `updateQuestionNumber` AND `render` run.

```
v.QuestionBuilder = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change:question_number', this.updateQuestionNumber, this);
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    //only this function should run when question_number is changed
    updateQuestionNumber: function(){
        this.$('.question-number').text(this.model.get('question_number'));
    },
    //this should run when anything except question_number is changed
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$el.fadeIn('slow');

        /* blah blah blah */
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution I could think of:

When this.render() fires I set an array non_render of properties which don't require a full render (are taken care of by `this.model.on('change:whatever', this.whateverRenderFunction, this);`). Then it checks the changedAttributes. If there is anything in there that's NOT in non_render (`._difference`) then it continues. Otherwise it returns.

This seems like a super-bulky solution though (and I have to maintain the non_render list both in `initialize` and in `render`. Any improvements would be awesome...

```
    render: function(model, value, options){
        if(model){ //this was triggered via .change()
            var changed = _.keys(model.changedAttributes());
            var non_render = ['question_number'];

            //if there is anything in changed that's not part of non_render
            if(_.difference(changed, non_render).length === 0){
                return false;
            }
        }

        var data = this.model.toJSON();
        _.extend(data, _.result(this.templateProperties));

        this.$el.html(this.template(data));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('change', function(model) {
        var changed = model.getChanged();
        if(changed && 1 === changed.length && changed.question_number) {
            this.updateQuestionNumber();
        } else {
            this.render()
        }
    }, this);
},
```

Comment: that works but say I had an array of parameters I wanted to exclude from causing a re-render (besides question_number).

Comment: Logic would be the same, just check array attributes. There's nothing like `model.on('change:[id,name,email]')` in backbone.